# How to tell if a thread responded to a wake up call?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, race-condition, worker

I'd like to read keyboard input directly from an input device. Reading from such a file requires root privileges which I don't need, and don't want, for the rest of the program.

My plan is to start the program with root privileges, then start a worker thread and finally drop root permissions in the main thread. The main thread can then send a request, asking the worker thread to process the next keyboard inputs.

I've constructed this minimal example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <threads.h>

cnd_t wakeup;
mtx_t mutex;

enum request {
  REQUEST_NOTHING,
  REQUEST_PING,
  REQUEST_TERMINATION
} request;

int daemon(void *arg) {
  (void)arg;

  int retval;

  retval = mtx_lock(&mutex);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  for(;;) {
    request = REQUEST_NOTHING;

    retval = cnd_wait(&wakeup, &mutex);
    assert(retval == thrd_success);

    switch(request) {
      case REQUEST_NOTHING:
        break;

      case REQUEST_PING:
        puts("pong.");
        break;

      case REQUEST_TERMINATION:
        retval = mtx_unlock(&mutex);
        assert(retval == thrd_success);
        return 0;

      default:
        assert(false);
    }
  }
}

void send(enum request req) {
  int retval;

  retval = mtx_lock(&mutex);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  request = req;

  retval = mtx_unlock(&mutex);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  // TODO race condition: worker thread my not be listening yet

  retval = cnd_signal(&wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);
}

int main() {
  int retval;

  retval = mtx_init(&mutex, mtx_plain);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  retval = cnd_init(&wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  thrd_t thread;
  retval = thrd_create(&thread, daemon, NULL);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  puts("ping.");
  send(REQUEST_PING);

  // TODO wait for the worker thread to complete

  send(REQUEST_TERMINATION);
  retval = thrd_join(thread, NULL);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  cnd_destroy(&wakeup);
  mtx_destroy(&mutex);
}
```

I currently haven't implemented the privileges thing, but I have enough problems already:

1. `cnd_signal` doesn't indicate whether the signal was received by anyone:

   > Unblocks one thread that currently waits on condition variable pointed to by cond. *If no threads are blocked, does nothing and returns `thrd_success`*.
   >   
   > <sub>Source: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/cnd_signal)</sub>

   This leads to a race condition because the main thread needs to lock the mutex before writing to `request`, but the worker thread needs to lock the mutex too before waiting for signals.
2. The main thread doesn't wait for the worker thread to finish. This isn't a problem in this example because *(1)* the main thread must wait to obtain the lock before sending the next request, and *(2)* the thread can simply be joined before exiting.

   In my actual program I need to wait though. The obvious solution would be to introduce another pair of `cnd_t` and `mtx_t` allowing the worker thread to wake up the main thread. But this seems overly complicated for such a simple problem.

I couldn't find many resources demonstrating the use of C11's threads library and probably on the wrong track all together. I'd appreciate some feedback and maybe a solution to the problems described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't have to permanently keep the `root` privileges in your process.
You don't need `root` to read from the input device. The permissions are only checked when opening it.

After opening the device your process can drop the `root` privileges and continue to do its work, reading from the open file descriptor as an unprivileged user, so you don't need a separate process or thread.

Dropping the extended privileges as early as possible is the standard procedure to implement access to special resources while minimizing the security risk.

See also https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/secure-programming-cookbook/0596003943/ch01s03.html

There might be other cases where you need to permanently keep special privileges. In such a case your idea of separating the tasks that require elevated privileges from other tasks is good, but you would have to use a separate process instead of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** While my problem was already solved by @dunes and I learned that permissions are handled on a process basis (thanks @solomon), I found it infuriating to leave this question without an answer which resolves the race condition itself.

---

As it turns out, I've just misunderstood how these `cnd_t` variables are supposed to be used. The trick is to lock the mutex **before** starting the worker thread and have it unlock the mutex when it's waiting for a signal. When signaling the thread the lock is obtained **before** signaling the thread and not released until the request has
been send and the signal went out.

This program doesn't have a race condition anymore:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <threads.h>

mtx_t mx_wakeup;
cnd_t cd_wakeup;

enum request {
  REQ_NOTHING,
  REQ_TERMINATE
} request;

int daemon(void *arg) {
  (void)arg;

  for(;;) {
    request = REQ_NOTHING;

    int retval = cnd_wait(&cd_wakeup, &mx_wakeup);
    assert(retval == thrd_success);

    if(request == REQ_TERMINATE) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

void send(enum request request_) {
  int retval;

  // The worker thread will unlock the mutex implicitly when
  // waiting for a signal, block until that happens.
  retval = mtx_lock(&mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  request = request_;

  retval = cnd_signal(&cd_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  // The worker thread needs to lock the mutex before waking up,
  // this ensures that it doesn't before receiving the signal.
  retval = mtx_unlock(&mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);
}

int main() {
  int retval;

  retval = mtx_init(&mx_wakeup, mtx_plain);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  retval = cnd_init(&cd_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  // The mutex will be unlocked by the worker thread when listening.
  retval = mtx_lock(&mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  thrd_t thread;
  retval = thrd_create(&thread, daemon, NULL);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  send(REQ_TERMINATE);

  retval = thrd_join(thread, NULL);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  cnd_destroy(&cd_wakeup);
  mtx_destroy(&mx_wakeup);
}
```

Waiting for the worker thread is just adding another condition variable now. Only the termination code
has to be adopted to release the mutex, otherwise the main thread will wait for the lock forever.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <threads.h>

mtx_t mx_wakeup;
cnd_t cd_wakeup, cd_complete;

enum request {
  REQ_NOTHING,
  REQ_TERMINATE
} request;

int daemon(void *arg) {
  (void)arg;
  int retval;

  for(;;) {
    request = REQ_NOTHING;

    retval = cnd_wait(&cd_wakeup, &mx_wakeup);
    assert(retval == thrd_success);

    // The request can be processed here.

    // Inform the main thread that the request was completed. The main
    // thread can choose to wait or not.
    retval = cnd_signal(&cd_complete);
    assert(retval == thrd_success);

    // Termination is different because the mutex wouldn't be released
    // by the next `cnd_wait`, and must happend after the signal was send.
    if(request == REQ_TERMINATE) {
      retval = mtx_unlock(&mx_wakeup);
      assert(retval == thrd_success);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

void send(enum request request_) {
  int retval;

  retval = mtx_lock(&mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  request = request_;

  retval = cnd_signal(&cd_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  // This unlocks the mutex thus allowing the worker thread to process the
  // request, thus the mutex can be reused here.
  retval = cnd_wait(&cd_complete, &mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  retval = mtx_unlock(&mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);
}

int main() {
  int retval;

  retval = mtx_init(&mx_wakeup, mtx_plain);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  retval = cnd_init(&cd_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  // Remember to initialize the new conditional variable.
  retval = cnd_init(&cd_complete);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  retval = mtx_lock(&mx_wakeup);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  thrd_t thread;
  retval = thrd_create(&thread, daemon, NULL);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  send(REQ_TERMINATE);

  retval = thrd_join(thread, NULL);
  assert(retval == thrd_success);

  cnd_destroy(&cd_wakeup);
  mtx_destroy(&mx_wakeup);
}
```